# Is the "present()" intrinsic evaluated at compile time

Tags: fortran, fortran90, optional-arguments

When dealing with `optional` arguments in `fortran` I believe it's typical to branch using the `present()` intrinsic, i.e.:

```
subroutine foo(ii,jj)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: ii
    integer, optional   :: jj

    if (present(jj)) then
! do something
    else
! do something else
    end if

end subroutine foo
```

My assumption (coming from a `C++` world) is that `present()` is hopefully a compile-time construct, and that there won't be any associated runtime performance penalty. I expect that the compiler should be able to (should be required to?) optimise the `if` statement shown above away, depending on whether `foo(ii)` or `foo(ii,jj)` is called.

How is the `present()` intrinsic handled by compilers in practice? Does the `fortran` spec guarantee certain behaviour?

Comment: `present()` is almost the same as checking if the pointer passed in C is `null` or not. Normally that is run-time. Both in C and Fortran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PRESENT is a runtime concept - to the extent that the presence of an argument may depend on aspects of the program that cannot be determined until runtime (based on input read from a file or similar).

The implementation of the equivalent of PRESENT in a C++ program would similarly be a runtime concept.  Note that C++'s defaulted arguments feature is not quite the same concept as Fortran's optional arguments feature (though it could be part of an equivalent implementation).

Beyond compiler optimization cleverness, if you want compile time resolution of things similar to C++'s defaulted arguments or function overloading, then consider using multiple specific procedures behind a generic name, one variant of the specific with the "optional" argument, the other without.

Answer (score 1):

That depends (what else did you expect? :-)

If you use gfortran with a recent version, and do a lot of work in at least one of the branches, and use LTO or put everything into one file, the compiler will clone the function for you (via constant propagation).  Otherwise, probably not.  If you want to find out if the procedure `foo` has been cloned, grep for `foo.*constprop` in the assembly file.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess the short answer seems to be: **no** -- in general you can't rely on `present()` being dealt with at compile time, so don't use it in routines called within tight loops. I must admit (compared to `C++` say) this surprises me somewhat. It's nice that `gfortran` is making progress here, but it sounds like the functionality is still under development.

Comment: If the routine is inlined (which it ought to be if it is called in a tight loop), then of course the compiler can do a lot. Keep in mind that gfortran and g++ share the same middle and back end, so something that will be inlined in g++ will also be inlined in gfortran.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to one subroutine with an optional argument is two subroutines, one with the argument, and one without, sharing the same interface. I don't think there is a run-time cost for doing this as opposed to giving the two versions of the subroutine different names. Schematically, it looks like this:

```
interface foo
   module procedure foo_1,foo_2
end interface foo

contains

subroutine foo_1(ii)
! some code

subroutine foo_2(ii,jj)
! some code
```